# Amazon EC2 NodeJS npm does not install modules

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I just configured a new micro intsance on amazon ec2.

I checked out node source code and build it.

Now i want to setup express and other node modules but npm does not work.

When i give command e.g. npm install express, it waits there without any further process.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try using the `--verbose` flag to get some extra info, like this: `npm install express --verbose`. What happens?

Comment: It stucks at : npm verb lock express@ /home/ubuntu/.npm/64a534c1-express.lock

Comment: Try `sudo su` before calling npm.